# How to get more than 20 results with the Twitter Search API

Tags: twitter

I'm using the [Twitter Search API](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search) to retrieve tweets for specific search terms from Twitter. It seems however that there is a limit of 20 tweets per result or some kind of date limit.

Does anyone know of a way to get more results?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Twitter search only goes back 5 - 7 days, or 1,500 tweets, whichever comes first. The search API is the same. Any tweets beyond that are not available through any known method. Twitter has them, but there is no way to get them. If you know in advance that you will want all tweets for some keywords or from some users, you need to use the streaming API to collect them in advance and save them in a database. Then you can search your database any time in the future to get all the tweets you have already saved.

Answer (score 8):

**1. Getting the first 1500 tweets**

Given the [GET search](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) resource from the Search API (Updated on Sat, 2011-07-09 10:06) you'll notice that by specifying the 'page' and 'RPP' (results per page) parameters, you can retrieve at most 1500 tweets, published no longer than 6-9 days ago.

**2. Getting *older* tweets**

To retrieve more tweets, you should first determine the lowest tweet id from step 1. Use this lowest id to set the 'max_id' parameter in a second GET search request (see [best practices](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) on using 'max_id'). The request will return tweets which all have a lower id than the ones from step 1. Repeat this approach until you get all the tweets published in the last 6-9 days.

It worked for me!

Comment: Can you share a code snippet on how that worked? and on which platforms?

Comment: have you implemented twitter search

Answer (score 1):

have you tried:

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=web&rpp=itemsperpage&page=pagenumber

Comment: Yes, and it still only returns me a couple of results. Almost looks like it's time limited. An example: http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=instagr.am+hermanschutte&rpp=20&page=1 this only returns 7 entries.

Comment: That is because only 7 entries were returned from your search.

Comment: Ah, ok. I see if I do the same search in the Twitter web front end it only shows 7 results and then tells me that older tweets are unavailable. Now the question is, does anyone know how to retrieve older tweets?

Comment: Thanks, that rrp argument was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Adam Green is dead on, 1.500 tweets or 7 days is all you get with the search API. However you can get more than 20 at a time by passing in the "rpp" parameter. Values for rpp must be between 1 and 1,500.

For example: search.twitter.com/search.json?&1=facebook&rpp=100

Be sure to read up on the stream api too... I ran into rate limits with the search api and it requires architecting your application differently.

http://af-design.com/blog/2010/12/17/reading-the-twitter-stream-api-with-php/

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that. Interesting how you can use Basic Auth for the streaming API. I thought they closed that down completely on the 16th of August.